# Expo crash once put <Text> inside <View> without error

Tags: react-native, crash, expo

This is the most weird thing in Expo i never face before. I try to design new UI. but this is the first time i face this kind of issue. If i put any hi at the position i mark "HERE", once i open that screen the app will crash without error. then i remove the hi, open back Expo, its ok

Feel free to test my code. I wonder why is this happen. If i put other than  such as  it works.
Ive tried few times, it is confirm the error cause by  only.

Ive tested on several IOS simulator, already restart the simulator even on my iphone SE 2020, it will result the same. Crashed without error

Please help me

```
<View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "#3341B0",
          height: screenHeight / 7,
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            alignItems: "flex-end",
            marginBottom: 20,
            width: screenWidth / 2,
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              width: 20,
              alignItems: "flex-start",
              justifyContent: "flex-start",
            }}
          ></View>
          <View
            style={{
              width: screenWidth,
              alignItems: "stretch",

              flexDirection: "column",
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: "700",
                fontStyle: "normal",
                color: "white",
              }}
            >
              {username !== "" && <Text>{`Hello ${username}`}</Text>}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 10,
                fontWeight: "700",
                fontStyle: "normal",
                color: "white",
              }}
            >
              Company : Testing
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            alignItems: "flex-end",
            marginBottom: 20,
            width: screenWidth / 2,
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 10,
              fontWeight: "700",
              fontStyle: "normal",
              color: "white",
            }}
          >
            Department : Sales and Marketing
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "#3341B0",
          alignItems: "flex-start",
          width: screenWidth,
          height: 250,
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "column",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            alignItems: "flex-start",
            width: screenWidth,
            height: 250,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              alignItems: "baseline",
              marginBottom: 10,
              marginTop: 10,
              marginLeft: 20,
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: "700",
                fontStyle: "normal",
                color: "black",
              }}
            >
              Work Orders
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              alignItems: "baseline",
              marginBottom: 10,
              marginLeft: 10,
              marginRight: 10,
              marginTop: 10,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                width: screenWidth / 3 - 20,
                height: 80,
                backgroundColor: "#041FFB",
                marginLeft: 10,
                borderRadius: 5,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >HERE</View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: screenWidth / 3 - 20,
                height: 80,
                backgroundColor: "#FBD15F",
                marginLeft: 10,
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}
            >HERE</View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: screenWidth / 3 - 20,
                height: 80,
                backgroundColor: "pink",
                marginLeft: 10,
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}
            >
              HERE
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: You'll have to wrap that `Hi` within a `<Text></Text>` component

Comment: tq for ur answer...i know that...i just found the real problem...i need to remove alignItems: "baseline", from the main view...and its works